# DynamicModule, SaveDefinitions and global functions

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, evaluation

---

#### Unfortunately, I had not checked stackoverflow, because there, the exact same behavior was already reported. Please see the Q&A ["SaveDefinitions considered dangerous"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579644/1078614).

---

Up-front, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with *Mathematica* 9.0.1 and let's start with the questions:

- Should functions which are used in a `Manipulate` be local to this dynamic cell, when I `save them with` SaveDefinitions`?
- Is it OK, that after a kernel-restart `Manipulate` defines global functions?

I noticed this behavior a while ago when something did not work as I expected it. Here is a small toy example. First we define a function, which (we assume we don't know this now) is not correct and will be fixed later:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := "Wrong Implementation";
```

Now we make a small dynamic environment where we use this function and we save the definitions used there.

```
Manipulate[f[x] + x, {x, 0, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Sliding a bit around gives the correct output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, we notice our error in `f`, because (let's say) `f` is going to work even when we don't have numeric values. Therefore, we fix the pattern and evaluate

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := "Correct Implementation!"
```

this redefinition is instantly shown in the `Manipulate`, which is kind of weird, because we explicitly told *Mathematica* to save the definition and let me cite the documentation: `SaveDefinition`...

> is an option to Manipulate and related functions that specifies whether **current definitions** relevant for the evaluation of the expression being manipulated should automatically be saved.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is even more, because when you now `Quit[]` the kernel and then do nothing else that move the slider, you see that now the first definition is used again and the output changes to `"Wrong Implementation"`. This seems fine, because `Manipulate` finally remembers what is should have saved.

However, this is not what broke my neck. What really took time to debug was that the wrong definition of `f` is leaked into the global context:

```
f[3]

(* "Wrong Implementation" *)
```

The problem back then, when I had this issue, was that although I evaluated the correct definition,

```
f[x_] := "Correct Implementation!"
```

the other one was used, because its pattern was more specific.

```
f[3]

(* "Wrong Implementation" *)
```

Any comments?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's really astounding how the exact same bug bites two people in the exact same way.

Comment: It's happened to me, too.  Sometimes I localize `f`: `Manipulate[x + f[x], {x, 0, 1}, {{f, f}, None}, Initialization :> (f[x_?NumericQ] := "Wrong Implementation")]`.  Sometimes if I need to redefine a function, I delete all the `Manipulate`/`DynamicModule` outputs and restart the kernel.  It certainly deserves a "Possible Issues" entry in the doc. page for `SaveDefinitions`, if not for `Manipulate` and `DynamicModule`.

Comment: I've been bit by this kind of thing as well. My solution is to only add `SaveDefinitions->True` as a final step before making .cdfs -- throughout development and any changes, leave `SaveDefinitions->False`.

Comment: I never use SaveDefinitions. Long time ago I noticed some strange behavior using it when making demo, which I could never understand why, may be it was this being discussed here, and since then I just use Initialization section.

Comment: @Nasser I rarely use it myself; often only in quick hacks but in this particular case, I spend quite some time with the  *quick* hack.

Comment: FWIW I never use `SaveDefinitions` ...not because I have encountered problems, but because I haven't had the need to use it. I keep variables local and mostly have functions global and use `Initialization` and never encounter issues/problems. I use `DynamicModule`, never `Manipulate`.