# How to be sure I've cleaned up all prior definitions and assignments

Tags: clear

1. Is there any general way besides restarting the kernel to make sure that nothing I've done earlier in a session will affect code I want to run now?

One book suggested running `Clear["Global'*"]` but this did not protect me from the problem illustrated below.

2. To verify whether I need to do something like restart the kernel, is there a way to get a list of all user definitions or assignments that are still in effect?

Background: I ran into a problem because I set y' equal to a+b*y, tried to clear y, found that y' was not a symbol, and  mistakenly thought that this assignment was no longer in effect even though it was. Eventually, I discovered that I had to use Remove[y] to undo this assignment.

```
In[1]:= y' = a + b*y
```

> ```
> Out[1]= a + b y
> ```

```
In[2]:= Clear[y]
ClearAll[y]
Clear["Global'*"]

In[5]:= Clear[y']
```

And getting an error

> In[5]:= Clear::ssym: y^[Prime] is not a symbol or a string. >>

```
In[6]:= Information[y']
```

> During evaluation of In[6]:= Information::ssym: y^[Prime] is not a symbol or a valid string pattern. >>
>
> Out[6]= Information[Derivative[1][y]]

```
In[7]:= ?y'
```

> During evaluation of In[7]:= Information::nomatch: No symbol matching y' found. >>

```
(* Looks like there is no trace of my assignment from line 1. And yet ... *) 

In[8]:= y'
```

> ```
> Out[8]= a + b y
> ```

```
In[9]:= Remove[y']
```

> During evaluation of In[9]:= Remove::ssym: y^[Prime] is not a symbol. >>

```
In[10]:= Remove[y]

In[11]:= y'
```

> ```
> Out[11]= Derivative[1][y]
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Lou, please edit the link. it is giving the current question.

Comment: Have you seen this [How to Clear variables with apostrophe?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15613/how-to-clear-variables-with-apostrophe?rq=1)

Comment: @Algohi, thanks for the hint, very thoughtful of you.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: [(850)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/850/121) -- the Accepted answer there is not a solution to your problem however.  Since I am not aware of any robust and practical way to clear all user definitions apart from simply quitting the Kernel I recommend you do that; see my answer there for a fast way to do this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard even that may not be enough. Remember that Manipulates with the SaveDefinition option set to true may inject definitions into a session as soon as the Manipulates come into view.

Comment: See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39631/dynamicmodule-savedefinitions-and-global-functions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I use

```
Remove["Global `*"]
```

(note that the first quotation is the left quotation mark associated with the tilde key, U.S. keyboard, not the single quote associated with the double quotation key.