# Strange Error with Initialization within Animate

Tags: initialization

```
Animate[x, {x, 0, h}, Initialization :> (h = 1)]
```

The code above gives the error:

*Animate::vsform: Animate argument {x,0,h} does not have the correct form for a variable specification. >>*

It's strange to me in that if `Animate` is replaced by `Manipulate`, no error is generated. What then is the reason for the error?

---

Comment: The error message seems clear to me. The 2nd argument of `Animate` is not a control specification, so you should not expect it have the same semantics as it would have if it were the 2nd argument of `Manipulate`. What are you really trying to accomplish by using an initialized variable in a range specification? Also, you might consider injecting a value with `With`.

Comment: In reply to the question asked, my original code, containing the structure exemplified by the simple code above, is much longer, and in there the range specification has to be calculated before the expression to be animated.

Comment: The reason I put that calculation within `Initialization` is that if it is placed outside `Animate`, then each time the notebook of this code is opened, `Animate` runs automatically - it runs without the range specification, hence errors appear.

Comment: Interesting, I thought `Animate` is just a `Manipulate` with `ControlType -> Animator`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sjoerd's investigation into the causes of the error is very fascinating, but in order to **prevent the error** it seems to me that you will want to use the **`SaveDefinitions -> True`** option, which "specifies whether current definitions relevant for the evaluation of the expression being manipulated should automatically be saved" ([docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html)).

I executed the following code in a new notebook, then saved the notebook, closed *Mathematica*, and reopened the saved notebook directly by double-clicking on it. *Mathematica* warned me about possibly dangerous dynamic content; I chose to enable the dynamic content, after which the animation re-started from where it had been paused without a hitch:

```
h = 3;
f[x_] := x;

Animate[
  Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, f[x]], PlotRange -> 3.6], {x, 0, h},
  SaveDefinitions -> True
]
```

Comment: This solution is perfect. Many thanks.

Comment: In addition, with this option one can also free themselves from certain cumbersome `Initialization` code inside `Manipulate` and `Animate`. So glad to have learned it.

Comment: @User18 I'm very glad I could help!

Comment: @User18 It should be noted that SaveDefinitions can be dangerous: [6579644](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous), [31998](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31998/the-dangers-of-savedefinitions-should-this-really-happen), [39631](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39631/dynamicmodule-savedefinitions-and-global-functions).

Comment: @Sjoerd  Oh, I should have logged in earlier. I see; indeed one should be cautious about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with the order in which the arguments of `Animate` are executed. Let's see if we can determine that:

```
ClearAll[eval, low, hi, init, x];
i = 1;
Animate[
   eval[If[i > 10, 10, i++]] = x,
   {x, low[i++] = x; 0, hi[i++] = x; 1}, 
   Initialization :> (init[i++] = x;), 
   AnimationRunning -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Information /@ {low, hi, init, eval};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, Mathematica first evaluates `Animate`'s lower bound, then its upper bound, then *repeats this process* (!?).

It then sets `Animate`'s running variable to the lower bound and *only then does it execute the initialization*.

Evaluation of the main body is the last step. Note that even though the animation isn't running (because of `AnimationRunning -> False`) the main body is evaluated continuously, just like in `Manipulate` since an assignment took place there, triggering a refresh.

Hence, the reason for your error is that you use the value set in the initialization in the animation bounds, but that part is executed earlier than the initialization.

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you very much.

Comment: Please allow me to ask a further question. As I mentioned in replying to m_goldberg, `Animate` runs automatically when the notebook containing it is open, but in certain cases we need the newly opened notebook to automatically calculate something else first, before `Animate` is activated. Is it possible to ensure that?

Comment: I'm afk at the moment. Have you tried AnimationRunning ->False?

Comment: Yes I tried that option, but it doesn't work. The following example can illustrate this:

Comment: `h = 3; f[x_] := x;
Animate[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, f[x]], PlotRange -> 3.6], {x, 0, h}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]`

Comment: Each time Mathematica is started afresh, and one opens the notebook where the above code and its output Animation window have been saved, there is an error, because, as you have pointed out, even though the animation isn't running the main body is evaluated continuously, but here without the required definitions for `h` and `f[x]`.